# Dash Plotly ImportError: cannot import name 'escape' from 'jinja2'

Tags: flask, jinja2, plotly-dash, importerror

I am trying to run a Dash app using a Python index.py file and keep getting an ImportError connected with the dash_core_components library.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Flask and jinja2 and this did not fix the problem.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lukeneuendorf/nfl_dashboard/index.py", line 1, in <module>
    import dash_core_components as dcc
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dash_core_components/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from dash.dcc import *  # noqa: F401, F403, E402
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dash/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .dependencies import (  # noqa: F401,E402
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dash/dependencies.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ._validate import validate_callback
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dash/_validate.py", line 5, in <module>
    import flask
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from jinja2 import escape
ImportError: cannot import name 'escape' from 'jinja2' (/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/__init__.py)
```

requirements.txt

```
  dash==2.7.1
  dash-core-components==2.0.0
  Flask==2.0.1
  Jinja2==3.0.3
  pandas==1.5.1
  plotly==5.3.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running it without a venv, so I created one. After downloading all the libraries it works now.